# Converting Pseudo Code To Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pseudocode

I am trying to convert this pseudo code into Python. I have no clue on how to do this. It looks simple to do but I have no knowledge of Python, making it almost impossible for me to do. This is the pseudo code:

```
Main Module

Declare Option

Declare value

Declare cost

While(choice ==’Y’)

Write “Vehicle Shipping Rates to Africa”

Write “1. Car to Ghana”

Write “2. Van to Nigeria”

Write “3. Truck to Togo”

Write “4. Van to Kenya”

Write “5. Truck to Somalia”

Write “Enter the choice:”

Get option

Write “Enter the car price:”

Get value

if ( option = 1)

cost = value / 0.30;

write “It would cost $”+cost "to ship a car that cost $” +value+"  to Ghana."

else if (option = 2)

cost = value / 0.20;

write “It would cost $”+cost "to ship a car that cost $” +value+"  to Nigeria."

else if ( option = 3)

cost = value / 0.33;

write “It would cost $”+cost "to ship a car that cost $” +value+"  to Togo."

else if (option = 4)

cost = value / 0.17;

write “It would cost $”+cost "to ship a car that cost $” +value+"  to Kenya."

else if ( option = 5)

cost = value / 0.31;

write “It would cost $”+cost "to ship a car that cost $” +value+"  to Somalia."

else

write “This is not a valid selection” “Please try again.”

endif

Write “Vehicle price you entered:”, value

Write “Shipping cost:”, cost

Write “Would you like to choose another selection, Y=Yes or N=No.”

Get choice

End while

Write “Thank you our application.”

End main module
```

Comment: SO is not a "write code for me" service. If you give it a go, we can provide advice on where you might be going wrong.

Comment: http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the reply. I know this isn't a write code for me place. I am just trying to know where to start from. A good starting point would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: I agree with Graeme Stuart that it is sometimes good to provide a solution to a beginner (unless one can feel it is a homework ;). Just, try to split your big question into many smaller ones. Ask the smaller questions if you cannot find the answer on your own.

Comment: You should start with learning programming first. Say, by reading head first python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to code something before posing on Stack Overflow. This will work but won't catch any error conditions.

```
options = [
    {'vehicle': 'Car', 'destination': 'Ghana', 'coeff': 0.3},
    {'vehicle': 'Van', 'destination': 'Nigeria', 'coeff': 0.2},
    {'vehicle': 'Truck', 'destination': 'Togo', 'coeff': 0.33},
    {'vehicle': 'Van', 'destination': 'Kenya', 'coeff': 0.17},
    {'vehicle': 'Truck', 'destination': 'Somalia', 'coeff': 0.31},
]
while True:
    print("Vehicle Shipping Rates to Africa")
    for i, opt in enumerate(options):
        print("%i. %s to %s" % (i+1, opt['vehicle'], opt['destination']))
    option = options[int(raw_input("Enter the choice:"))]
    value = float(raw_input("Enter the car price:"))
    cost = value / option['coeff']
    print("It would cost $%s to ship a %s that cost $%s to %s." % (cost, option['vehicle'], value, option['destination']))
    print("Vehicle price you entered: %s" % value)
    print("Shipping cost: %s" % cost)
    again = raw_input("Would you like to choose another selection, Y=Yes or N=No.")
    if again.lower() == 'n':
        break
print("Thank you our application.")
```

Comment: Thank you Graeme. I really do appreciate it, I am new to python and i am currently trying to self learn this programing language.

Comment: @user2852610 Note that this code is not a 1:1 translation of your pseudocode, but does a lot of condensing and uses a lot of python idioms.